# Can't use string ("VIEW_hash") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at test.pl line 10

Tags: perl, hash

Hi i really need a variable as hash name. But I am getting this errors. Can someone help??

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my %VIEW_hash = ( 'a' => 'A', 'b' => 'B', 'c' => 'C');
my $X = "VIEW";
my $name = "$X"."_hash";

foreach my $in (keys %$name){
    print "$in -- $$name{$in}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I doubt that you *really* need to do it this way. Most likely, you are just wanting to break the rules because you don't know a better way to do it.

Consider using a hash to store the textual links to your actual array:

```
my %VIEW_hash = ( 'a' => 'A', 'b' => 'B', 'c' => 'C');
my $X = "VIEW";
my $name = "$X"."_hash";

# Our new code
my %meta = ( "VIEW_hash" => \%VIEW_hash );
my $href = $meta{$name};

say @$href{"a".."c"};
say $href->{a}
```

Comment: I agree, don't break the rules. Do it only if you really have to, and only when there aren't other ways to get your job done.

Answer (score 2):

I changed something but this may fit your needs.

First of all you have to use the `no strict 'refs'` pragma, in order to use symbolic references. Then you have to switch from lexical variable to package variable ( defined with `our` ).

I choose to limit the extension of the strictures free zone to a block enclosed with curly braces: it may save you a couple of headaches in the future.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
{
    no strict 'refs';
    our %VIEW_hash = ( 'a' => 'A', 'b' => 'B', 'c' => 'C');
    my $X    = 'VIEW';
    my $name = "$X".'_hash';

    foreach ( keys %$name ) {
        printf "%s -- %s\n", $_, $$name{ $_ };
    }
}
```